# Error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>'

Tags: c++, macos, vector, stl, stdvector

I currently have a compilation problem on Mac (MacOS Big Sur v11.1). I'm trying to create a vector iterator using the STL. But I get an error:

> calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>'

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
int range_array[] = {42, 21, 123456, 0, 4, 13};
std::vector<int>::iterator stl_iterator(&(range_array[0]));
```

Here is my clang info (clang++ -v):

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Yeah, no. You can't abuse the standard library like that. What is this [meant to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I have a student project in which I have to recreate some STL containers, including "vector" and I wanted to compare it with the real STL...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a `std::vector<int>::iterator` and initialize it to refer something that's not contained in a `vector<int>`.

Why do you think that's a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: You mean i don't have the right type for range_vector ?

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in the [answer from Marshall Clow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69153667/10871073), a `std::vector<int>::iterator` *must* refer to a position in an *actual* `std::vector<int>` (or to its 'one-past-the-end' placeholder) – but your `range_array` isn't such a container. So, that `range_array` needs to be declared as a `std::vector<int>`.

Second, although a `std::iterator` object has some things in common with a pointer, it is **not** a pointer, and can't be initialized with the address of an  element. To set it to refer to the first element of a vector, use the [`begin()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) of the `std::vector`.

Here's a possible alternative to your code:

```cpp
std::vector<int> range_array = { 42, 21, 123456, 0, 4, 13 };
std::vector<int>::iterator stl_iterator{ range_array.begin() };
```